# Kubuntu 18.04 - Unable to configure wallpaper

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 a few months ago and the time to take over the operating system I came to the configuration of the appearance. Unfortunately I can not change the wallpaper! If I right click on the desktop I have access only to the general settings and in the general settings I can't find any menu to change the wallpaper.

Thanks for the help

Version of KDE Plasma: 5.12.6

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, please post a screenshot of what you see when you right-click on your desktop. If you don't know how to take a delayed screenshot, read on. **1**: press *Print Screen* to launch *Spectacle*. **2**: select "Current screen". **3**: set a delay to suit your convenience. **4**: click on "Take a new screenshot" at which point the Spectacle interface goes away. **5**: Right-click, on the desktop and wait for the delay to complete. **6**: click on the Spectacle icon in the taskbar. **7**: choose "Save and Exit". **8**: You can crop the image using *Gwenview*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I right-click on the desktop itself, I get a context menu. The item of interest is "Configure Desktop". Click on that.

[image: Configure Desktop]

You'll get a window titled "Desktop Folder Settings --- Plasma" if you've enabled the option to view folders on the desktop. Otherwise, the window will be titled "Desktop Folder --- Plasma".

[image: Desktop Settings]

Either way, look at the left pane/column. The first item should be *Wallpapers*. If it isn't, please edit your question providing a screenshot of what you see.

There's also an option to download additional wallpapers:

[image: More wallpapers]